# Changing (updating) self.title in navigationBar on scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uiscrollview

So what I'm trying to do is to write a simple gallery app - detail view behaves pretty much like the PhotoScroller provided by Apple in their sample code section on developer.apple.com, that is it allows the user to swipe across all the images. What I'd like to do is to update the title property on users swipe, in other words, if the user changes the image she's looking at, the self.title property should update itself to that photo's title. I know that is possible, since Apple's own Photo app is capable of displaying the current index ("1 of x"). How can this be done? I'd really appreciate any suggestions and thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using scroll view which contains many images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you scroll the `ScrollView` after ending the scrolling

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

method is call. So You can give the title inside this method. First Make an array of your all
Image's title. Then if your image's width is 320, then use this :-

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
  {
     int index = scrollView.contentOffset.x / 320;
     self.title = [titleArray objectAtIndex:index];
  }
```

Comment: This works great, and Kenpachi's answer is also spot on, but the problem is that the title in the navigationBar does not update itself with the new title. Is there a way to reload that navigationBar?

Comment: I think it should update itself .... it had been work on button's click... i didn't try it with scrollView's delegate method...but it should work ....

Comment: hey its working and navigationBar title is changing every time, no need to call anything.....please check your code again :-)

Comment: I think my problem might be the fact that I'm pushing the UIScrollView from a UITableView's cell, so that's not the same navigationController... I'll have to work that out somehow :/ Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Welcome ...and all the best :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are putting images in a scroll view then this method will give you the page number you are currently in:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSInteger pageNum = (int)(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"page no is:%d",pageNum);

    [self updateTitleForIndex: pageNum];
}

- (void)updateTitleForIndex:(NSInteger) pageNum
{
    //set title using your page number
    //also call this method initially for setting title
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a paged UIScrollView, the best approach would be to do the manipulation of the title in the delegate method called

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a method of `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol, such as `-scrollViewDidScroll:`